# Creating many relationships in one script

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a relative newbie to the world of cypher programming, and therefore hoping for a solution to this problem from the experts community here.

I am creating a graph from an excel file, which contains different categories, items and so on. One item can belong to multiple categories and so on.

I have generated the relevant create relationship statements (there are about 200 of them). However, when i put them through neo4j browser, the interface complains that i can only run one match - create command at a time.

i am not using any other programming language or their API and simply using neo4j browser to achieve this.

Kindly suggest path forward.

my env : neo4j desktop 4.1.3 on Windows 10 Enterprise.
apoc plugin is enabled, but i m not using it yet.

Thanks
raghav

Comment: Can you please post your import script and a sample of the data you are importing?

Comment: Also, show the error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

By default, Neo4j Browser only allows one Cypher statement to be executed at a time. This can be changed by going to the browser settings on the sidebar (gear icon), and then checking the `Enable multi statement query editor` checkbox. Afterward, you should be able to execute multiple Cypher statements on the query editor.